# GFCI breaker in the bathroom

Tags: bathroom, receptacle, gfci

I thought I had turned off the power in the bathroom but the outlet was still hot .  The gfci breaker tripped.  Now I have installed new outlets and I am not getting power after turning the breaker back on.  Is there something else to check for

Comment: Test if power is going though the breaker with a meter.  The short might have burnt out the breaker.  Good reason to always double check for power, before finding out with your fingers.

Comment: you are confusing the breakers

Comment: Best to turn off the main breaker in non-new homes, as you just never now what years, shoddy upgrades and lax previous code standards (think: no handle-ties on MWBCs) have left behind.

Comment: Make sure you're resetting it correctly:  turn it all the way off, then click it on. It's different than just turning a breaker off and then back on.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't indicated how old the wiring is in your home. In some instances the outlet/s in one bath are protected by a GFCI in another bathroom or even the garage. Check and be sure all the other GFCI outlets in the home are not tripped.

Comment: The house and the wiring are 20 years old

Comment: RMDman the one GFCI outlet in a bathroom across the house was tripped .  The rest weren’t but now the problem is solved.  Thank you for the information.